# Using TexStudio and TexLive -- Error: Could not start command

Tags: errors, texlive, compiling, texstudio

I'm fairly new to LaTex, and I'm having some trouble getting it up and running on my computer. I just installed TeX Live and TeXstudio 2.10.4 on my computer (which is running Windows 8). In TeXstudio, any time I try to compile a document, I receive the following error message:

```
Could not start Build & View:PdfLaTeX: 
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "testFile".tex
```

I've seen it suggested in many forums to go into in the `Options> Configure TeXstudio> Commands> PdfLaTeX`, then type the full path to `pdflatex.exe`. I've tried this, and it gives the following error message:

```
Could not start Build & View:PdfLaTeX: 
C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "testFile".tex
```

I also saw it suggested to put quotes around the path to `pdflatex.exe`. I tried this, and received the same error message as above, but with quotes around the path. Does anybody have any suggestions for how I can fix this issue? Thanks.

**Edit:**
When I run pdflatex from a Dos prompt the following occurs:

[image]

Comment: Just for fun what happens if you start a dos prompt and just run pdflatex, does it actually react?

Comment: @daleif I tried running pdflatex from a dos prompt. I'll updated my question with the corresponding output.

Comment: Hmm, there was some issues a few days ago have you tried updating? From the command line you can use `tlmgr update --self --all` (double minus)

Comment: @daleif Thanks for the suggestion. I just ran the update command you suggested. Unfortunately when I tried to run pdflatex afterwards I received the same output as before.

Comment: I deleted the first comment (as the log you showed answered it)

Comment: You might be best to ask on the texlive list (tex-live@tug.org) where the people who maintain those scripts can be found.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the suggestion. I'll ask there shortly.

Comment: @daleif I'm not sure if it's relevant, but the first time I tried to install TeXlive I received a message when the installation was almost complete saying an error occurred and that the installation couldn't be completed. I tried to install again and it seemed like everything worked properly.